# CSS and HTML will not link

Tags: html, css

I have been using external stylesheets just fine until a couple days ago. I don't know why I am no longer able to link to external stylesheets from my HTML since I have had no problems with it earlier. I absolutely cannot find the issue.
It will probably be obvious, but right now I am **really** frustrated.
Please Help!

My File Structure:

`-Tutorial (folder)
  - index.html
  - stylesheet.css`

```css
h1 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Hello</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Testing...</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Note: *It may run fine here on the snippet... but it **will not link** correctly in my HTML.*

Comment: do you have any errors in your browser console?

Comment: Can you see stylesheet directly in browser? `http://example.com/stylesheet.css`

Comment: Might be a permissions issue, following Xaqron's suggestion will tell.

Comment: @Pyromonk: permission plus webserver issue with css files do to a misconfig.

Comment: If I go to the web console, I can see the css link in my 'head', but if I view the page source, the css file link will not work. If I directly target it in my url... It says that file does not exist!

Comment: tried clearing your browser cookies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks you guys for the help! I found that I had this in my head:

```
<link rel="stylsheet" href="stylesheet.css">
```

I had spelled stylesheet wrong in the 'rel'.
It works fine now!

Answer (score 0):

use

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheet.css">
```

Comment: Thanks! Though this did not do anything different.